# Cannot create instance of type '%0' - error in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: .net, xaml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I want to get some sample data to a ViewModel, which contains data to bind in XAML. Here is the code:

```
    private NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<Auction>> _recentAuctions;

    public NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<Auction>> RecentAuctions
    {
        get
        {
            return _recentAuctions;
        }
        set
        {
            _recentAuctions = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RecentAuctions");
        }
    }

    public MainMenuViewModel()
    {
        RecentAuctions = new NotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<Auction>>(dataService.GetRecentAuctions());
    }
```

(it uses `NotifyTaskCompletion` pattern from [MDSN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx))

GetRecentAuctions method:

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Auction>> GetRecentAuctions()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Auction>
        {
            new Auction
            {
                Percentage = "69",
                Title = "Szybsza spłata",
                Date = "przed chwilą"
            },
            new Auction
            {
                Percentage = "33",
                Title = "Kolejna pożyczka, tym razem na remont.",
                Date = "1 minutę temu"
            }
        };
    }
```

So far it works well - the items are displayed in `<ListView>`.
The problem begins when I want to test whether or not it can work asynchronously, to do it I add this "await" line:

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Auction>> GetRecentAuctions()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return new ObservableCollection<Auction>
        {
            ...
```

and I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XXX.exe
>   'XXX.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.NI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in XXX.exe
>   **WinRT information: Cannot create instance of type '%0'** [Line: 16 Position: 10]

**Can anyone explain this behavior?** What is missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say, but what it looks like to me is that you are trying to asynchronously load data in the constructor of the `ViewModel`, the problem is that the VM will finish creation before the data is loaded.  If you are referencing any of the data items in the code that are expected to be initialized you could run into the `System.NullReferenceException`

I would recommend that if you want to load data asynchronously, not to do it in the VM constructor.

You can use the Behaviors SDK to hook into the Loaded event of the page which then calls into your VM.